# How to create/ add custom fields through extracting data from another existing field in Microsoft Azure Log Analytics workspace?

Tags: extract, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to use the extract fields from feature to extract data from existing fields like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5CFd.png)

But Microsoft has removed this option. So I'm looking for an alternative way to parse the collected data from 'RawData' into individual properties.

For some reason, I can't get a working solution. I have read the Microsoft documentation but haven't been able to figure it out as of yet!

I appreciate your help

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/custom-fields

The document that I believe has my potential answer:
1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/parse-text

Also maybe useful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/custom-fields-migrate

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your "RawData" and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

We have been improving the ingestion capabilities over the last couple of years and we now have Ingestion Time transformations, which greatly improves upon the custom field extraction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-transformations.

Depending on how you are ingesting the logs, you may be required to update to the newer Azure Monitor Agent or the new API for ingesting the data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-custom-text-log-migration